# Ng If does not work in observable variable in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have integrated the Angular6 material data grid with server side pagination as per this link
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

Here, I want to display the "No Data Found", if the data set is empty from the response.
I could take the totalCount which is mapped Observable and I can print the view as below. But, ngIf does not work.

```
  private totalCountSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public totalCount$ = this.totalCountSubject.asObservable();
  this.totalCountSubject.next([body.data.count]);

  // View
  {{dataSource.totalCount$}} <!-- It displayes 0 or count of the row -->

   <!-- It does not work. --->
   <span *ngIf="(dataSource.totalCount$ | async) === 0 ">
     NO DATA FOUND!!!!
   </span>
```

Any idea why ngIf does not work in this case.

Comment: do you use dataSource.totalCount$ twice in your view?

Comment: Try: **ngIf="(your_data | async)?.length === 0"*

Comment: @ABOS Yes, for pagination as 
<mat-paginator [length]="dataSource.totalCount$ | async" [pageSize]="1"
                ></mat-paginator>

Comment: @PrashantPimpale it does not work.

Comment: I played with a similar implementation but found it worked https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfpxfg, and you can change value in HelloComponent's  ngOnInit() {
    this.subject.next(0);
  } to see it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

handle the condition with nested `ngIf` s

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataSource.totalCount$ | async as totalCount">  
   <span *ngIf="totalCount == 0 ">
     NO DATA FOUND!!!!
   </span>

<ng-container>
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `===` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdvr6w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It works good. Thank you. Can you answer this question also if you can.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658637/nested-list-populated-in-angular-6-material-data-table